# How to get profile details to a website using Linkedin API?

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

How can I get my own profile details to a website using latest LinkedIn javascript API with Oauth 2.0?

**Goal is to to keep the website up to date using linked profile.**

Tried below,

```
api_key: YOUR_API_KEY_HERE
authorize: true
onLoad: onLinkedInLoad

// Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
function onLinkedInLoad() {
    IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
}

// Handle the successful return from the API call
function onSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

// Handle an error response from the API call
function onError(error) {
    console.log(error);
}

// Use the API call wrapper to request the member's profile data
function getProfileData() {
    IN.API.Raw("/people/~:(id, first-name, skills, educations, 
           languages, twitter-accounts)").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
}
```

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin

Im not sure how exactly I should do this, can someone give me a tip to get start? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the JavaScript wrapper implementation of it as i have done it in Java . But here  is a nice tutorial using JQuery using basic REST implementation that fetches a user's data . Hope this helps you ,and get you started  : ) .  http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2012/08/how-to-fetch-twitter-profile-information-using-jQuery-plugin-as-json-object.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks, ill check that and get back to you. :)